# convert PDF to JPEG in PHP using ZEND server

Tags: php, html, css, image, zend-framework

I'm using a script to convert PDF to JPG Online. But when i run this script on zend server and upload any pdf file then the file is upload on the server & it show broken images on the browser.

I use one folder and one index file where this code is written.

1. upload folder
2. index.php file

Here is the script I am running:

```
    <html>
 <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      img {border-width: 0}
      * {font-family:'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;}
    </style>
 </head>
<body>

<?php
$message = "";
$display = "";
if($_FILES)
{
    $output_dir = "uploads/";
    ini_set("display_errors",1);
    if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
    {
        $RandomNum   = time();

        $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
        $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

        $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
        $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
        if($ImageExt != "pdf")
        {
            $message = "Invalid file format only <b>\"PDF\"</b> allowed.";
        }
        else
        {
            $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
            $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $NewImageName);

            $location   = "/usr/local/bin/convert";
            $name       = $output_dir. $NewImageName;
            $num = count_pages($name);
            $RandomNum   = time();
            $nameto     = $output_dir.$RandomNum.".jpg";
            $convert    = $location . " " . $name . " ".$nameto;
            exec($convert);
            for($i = 0; $i<$num;$i++)
            {
                $display .= "<img src='$output_dir$RandomNum-$i.jpg' title='Page-$i' /><br>"; 
            }
            $message = "PDF converted to JPEG sucessfully!!";
        }
    }
}
function count_pages($pdfname) {
      $pdftext = file_get_contents($pdfname);
      $num = preg_match_all("/\/Page\W/", $pdftext, $dummy);
      return $num;
    }
$content = $message.'<br />'.$display.'<br><form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
 Please choose a file: <input name="myfile" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>';


echo $content;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The broken Image is:

[image]

Comment: I would advise adding an example of how the broken image looks.

Comment: The image is looks like 2nd image of this link. http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_broken_image_00_a_logo.gif

Comment: `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /brandnew/archives/google_broken_image_00_a_logo.gif on this server.`

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius Sorry for that link. Now i put this image on the question.

Comment: Try to replace `exec($convert);` with `system($convert . " 2>&1");`. This should display a (hopefully meaningful) error message.

Comment: @Phillip Its shows error.

Comment: Really only the single word "error"?

Comment: Its shows 6 Warning and at last display "The system cannot find the path specified. PDF converted to JPEG sucessfully!!"

Comment: Is there any other way to view PDF on browser using PHP.

Comment: Sure there is other ways how to show PDFs in browser! Just *google*.

Comment: You should try prepending `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to your `$output_dir` variable in order to have an absolute path.

Comment: Are you certain that `/usr/local/bin/convert` exists? If it does not, using image magick directly via [the PHP extension](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/class.imagick.php) is an alternative. AFAIK, the documentation has some contributed examples for PDF conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you asking view PDF on browser.
Try this online [pdf viewer](http://viewerjs.org/instructions/).
[Download](http://viewerjs.org/releases/ViewerJS-latest.zip) it and Enjoy. I hope it is use full for you.

Comment: This is a good comment but that does not answer the question. It is an opinion